# Duplicate color for Gauge of Google Chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, google-visualization, gauge

I need to have two red colors on my gauge, like this:

```
$scope.gauge1.options = {
  width: 200,
  height: 90,

  redFrom: 0,
  redTo: 10,

  yellowFrom: 10,
  yellowTo: 20,

  greenFrom: 20,
  greenTo: 30,

  redFrom: 30,
  redTo: 100,

  minorTicks: 5
};
```

But when I duplicate the red color my first red color does not appear.

The same color does not appeat two times on the gauge.

There is some way to do it or add one more color to the gauge?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

use the overlapping colors
https://jsfiddle.net/cenee32j/

```
$scope.gauge1.options = {
  width: 200,
  height: 90,

  redFrom: 30, 
  redTo: 60,

  greenFrom: 0, 
  greenTo: 100,

  yellowFrom:10, 
  yellowTo: 90,

  minorTicks: 5
};
```